# Import SUMO network into Unity

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, sumo

I want to build a `2D Road network using SUMO`, it's an open source, highly portable, microscopic and continuous road traffic simulation package designed to handle large road networks.

> I exported the network as `.net.xml` file, but i don't know how to import it into Unity to generate `a 3D Network.`
>   any suggestion please?!

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple import functionality that I know of, however there have been various attempts to build a unity frontend:

- https://github.com/DarraghMac97/Real-time-Traffic-Simulation-with-3D-Visualisation
- https://github.com/danielbuechele/SumoVizUnity
- https://github.com/Andrew-Stebel/Unity-SUMO